# How to migrate HttpResponse and HttpRequest in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm in the process of migrating my .net framework application to .net core. I'm having a bit of trouble to migrate HttpResponse. My class basically wraps the object.

For example

```
public class HttpResponseWrapper 
{
    private readonly HttpResponse _response;

    public bool Buffer { get { return _response.Buffer; } set { _response.Buffer = value; } }
    public bool BufferOutput { get { return _response.BufferOutput; } set { _response.BufferOutput = value; } }
    public void AddCacheDependency(params CacheDependency[] dependencies)
    {
        _response.AddCacheDependency(dependencies);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately HttpResponse is undefined. I'm also doing the same for HttpRequest.

I tried adding `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.` but everything breaks. Anywhere where response is used, it'll say it doesn't contain a definition for `Buffer/Bufferoutput/etc.`

Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `HttpResponseMessage`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

You handle requests and responses in your controller classes and action filters. Of course you can pass these objects to some other methods later on.

- Your `Controller` classes should inherit from `Controller` class, which inherits from `ControllerBase` class. `ControllerBase` class has `Request` and `Response` properties (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-5.0).
- In action filters, a context object is passed to the constructor or to an overridable method. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.authorizationfiltercontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0 for an example. You can use `context.HttpContext.Request` and `context.HttpContext.Response` in that case.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem at hand. I'm not in the context of a controller. I am not exposed to context.HttpContext.Request. This doesn't allow me to continue reusing my class.